# MediaPlayerLauncher error when launching bigger videos

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a problem with MediaPlayerLauncher in which trying to play a video that I know is over 10mb will come up with a "not supported" message and go back to the app.

Is there a way to launch MediaPlayerLauncher using some other progressive streaming setting.